# How is the 3 terminal gas discharge tube grounded for rs 422 protection?

Tags: rs485, rs422

I took over an unfinished project. Here, gas discharge protection is used for rs422 protection. 2 different grounds are used in the project. And the middle point of the gas discharge tube seems to be connected to the chasis ground. When I examine the reference designs, I see two different connections. The midpoint is connected directly to the gnd and in the other design the chasis is connected to the chasis ground island . Which is the better option?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A disembodied "GND" symbol doesn't really tell us anything about the application. Have you considered they were simply using the symbol for convenience? Perhaps the device was bolted to a chassis, or protective earth?

Comment: Where did the designs you posted come from?